Kanamori, The Higher Infinite: Levy collapse, Propositions 10.20 and 10.21
I have a question regarding Kanamori's book The Higher Infinite, propositions 10.20 and 10.21.
Proposition 10.20 states:
Let $\mathbf{P} = (P, \leq)$ be a separative forcing notion with $\lvert P \rvert \leq \lvert \alpha \rvert$, $ \alpha \in \Omega$ and satisfying the following condition
$$\Vdash_P \exists f (f: \omega \rightarrow \alpha \ \text{is surjective} \land f \notin V_{\cdot}).$$
In this case, there exists an injective, dense embedding $e: D \rightarrow P$ where $D$ is
dense subset of Col$(\omega,\lbrace \alpha \rbrace)$.
Proposition 10.21 states:
Let $\kappa > \omega$ be a regular cardinal. Let $G$ be a Col$(\omega, \kappa)$-generic filter. For all $x \in V[G]$ where $x: \omega \rightarrow \Omega$ exists a filter $H$  being Col$(\omega, \kappa)$-generic over $V[x]$ and satisfying $V[G] = V[x][H]$.
My question: In the proof of 10.21 he applies prop. 10.20 to Col$(\omega, \delta+1)$in order to show that there is a Col$(\omega, \delta+1)$-generic filter over a certain model V[x].
How do we apply prop. 10.20 to Col$(\omega, \delta+1)$? Do we apply it for each $\alpha < \delta+1$ and this results then in Col$(\omega,\lbrace \alpha \rbrace)$ = Col$(\omega, \delta+1)$?
Thank you very much for any help in advance.

$\operatorname{Col}(\omega,\delta+1)$ adds an onto function from $\omega$ to $\delta$ that is not in $V$.
